# can't start jupyter notebook in Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, navigator

Whenever I start Jupyter notebook in Anaconda navigator I get the following error.
When I try to go in browser to localhost:8888 nothing happens. It seems that internal web server is not working. Does anyone have a possible solution?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\AndromedaFX\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\Users\AndromedaFX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 64, in 
from tornado import httpserver
File "C:\Users\AndromedaFX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\httpserver.py", line 32, in 
from tornado.http1connection import HTTP1ServerConnection, HTTP1ConnectionParameters
File "C:\Users\AndromedaFX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\http1connection.py", line 34, in 
from tornado import iostream
File "C:\Users\AndromedaFX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\iostream.py", line 40, in 
from tornado.netutil import ssl_wrap_socket, _client_ssl_defaults, _server_ssl_defaults
File "C:\Users\AndromedaFX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\netutil.py", line 39, in 
_client_ssl_defaults = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
File "C:\Users\AndromedaFX\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 589, in create_default_context
context.load_default_certs(purpose)
File "C:\Users\AndromedaFX\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 490, in load_default_certs
self._load_windows_store_certs(storename, purpose)
File "C:\Users\AndromedaFX\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 482, in _load_windows_store_certs
self.load_verify_locations(cadata=certs)
ssl.SSLError: nested asn1 error (_ssl.c:3956)
```

Comment: 1 try to reboot the computer 2 Which os you have? if is windows try [netsh](https://iihelp.iinet.net.au/Resetting_Network_Adapter_(Winsock_Reset))

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the following link to solve this problem.

```
https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/troubleshooting.html
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing didnt help, until I did a clean install of Win10 :)